# Prevent video record specification override on Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building an android app using Android Studio and wanted to know how can I prevent someone from exploiting my app that overriding the `setVideoFrameRate` and `video size` that I set in my application. I understand that I can make my methods `private` and `final` but I feel like I am missing something.

I will be storing the videos so if someone can exploit it then my storage will go crazy.

Thank you.

Comment: Encrypt file by default, decrypt while playing, and encrypt immediately after done playing. you need code sample?

Answer (score 0):

If you aware if someone could steal your code - bad news there isn't absolutely guaranteed way to save your code, but it's possible to make it almost non-understandable. It called obfuscation. Use [proguard](https://link.medium.com/KOkET8KuwR) as buildin tool  for that.
If you think that someone can copy your video that is stored in inner memory (aka app directory) - you [need](https://link.medium.com/5xKPvdavwR) to [encrypt](https://gist.github.com/aliab/8cc7c4b9f8cbda263dc7) it somehow. There are a lot of tutorials how to make it on Android. 
If you think that someone could invoke your method from outside apps scope - with out proper logic in your app it's impossible.

Comment: I tried googling but couldnt find could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Updated my answer